# Using beamer document class

Tags: packages

I'm using `\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}` with the package Tikzcd but it doesn't work properly with the frames. It gives me the error:

> Package pgf Error: Single ampersand used with wrong catcode. \end{frame}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted in section 3.4 of the `tikz-cd` manual, you can use the `ampersand replacement` key to solve this:

```latex
\documentclass[]{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{}{}
  \begin{tikzcd}[ampersand replacement=\&]
    A \ar[r]\& B 
  \end{tikzcd}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```